# vb.net Parameters Startup Form not hiding?

Tags: vb.net, forms, parameters, hide, process.start

I am creating a application to be used with a touch panel device. The touch panel device comes with a standard windows OSK (On screen Keyboard). Whilst testing its been concluded that the standard OSK is to large and too complex for what we need it in. So I have built my own OSK. some of the feilds though only requier numeric inputs so I though of futher simplifying the process by creating a new form which hosts a numeric pad. so far this is all working. the idea is then to have the app which ask for diffrent inputs then to trigger the OSK application, say that the user wants to enter a phonenumber in one textbox I then want to start the OSK app using a parameter that trigers the OSK to start the NumericForm form first... this too I have working but the thing I can't get right is to hide the AlphabetForm I have tried the following method but am a little stumpt on how to get this right

In short its the Me.hide which isnt working as expected?

```
    Private Sub AlphabetForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

#Region "Recive startup parameters (if any)"
        Try
            Dim OSKParameters As String = Command()

            If OSKParameters = "OSKNUM" Then
                NumericForm.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                ShiftSelect = 0
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Do nothing
        End Try
#End Region
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot this be decided in the `Startup` event (`OnStartup` override)? Read the command line there and decide what Form to show. The StartUp event is raised before the startup form is created. The executable that creates the OSK can also be just a stub that loads a specific Form from a .dll based on parameters.

Comment: I am familiar with the Startup event and have moved the code there, that hasn't worked so im guessing I need to implement the override however Im not farmilliar with that, nor is googeling it now showing me any examples of its use? in my projects folder it wants me to refrence a start up form i think that keeps causeing the trouble but i can only refrence forms here?

Comment: In `Namespace My -> Partial Friend Class MyApplication` add `Protected Overrides Function OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs) As Boolean [...]  Return MyBase.OnStartup(e) End Function`. In case you want to use the ApplicationFramework. Otherwise, much better IMO, disable the ApplicationFramework and start from Sub Main (`Sub Main((args() As String)`, so you have direct control on what's run before anything starts, get the command line arguments and run the *right* Form based on the switch(es) passed in.

Comment: If you override `OnStartup`, you can simply write `My.Application.MainForm = NumericForm` and that will be the new starting Form (not what is specified in `Project->Properties->Application`). I prefer to run an app from `Sub Main` (`void Main()`), but that's just my preference.

Comment: Why change the form at all? Why not use a single form and simply change its appearance based on what needs to be displayed? Create two user controls - one a keyboard and one a number pad - and then just display whichever is appropriate and resize the form accordingly?

Comment: By the way, you might like to check [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?459890) out for some useful types for building an OSK.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible setups, as described in comments:

► Using the [Application Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase), override [`OnStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.onstartup) and set [Application.MainForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.mainform) to a Form object determined by a command-line argument:

To generate `ApplicationEvents.vb`, where `Partial Friend Class MyApplication` is found, open the Project properties, `Application` pane, click the **`View Application Events`** Button: it will add the `ApplicationEvents.vb` file to the Project if it's not already there.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    '[...]
    Protected Overrides Function OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs) As Boolean
        Application.MainForm = If(e.CommandLine.Any(
            Function(cmd) cmd.Equals("OSKNUM")), CType(NumericForm, Form), AlphabetForm)
        Return MyBase.OnStartup(e)
    End Function
    '[...]
End Class
```

► Disabling Application Framework, to start the Application from `Sub Main()`.

In the **`Project->Properties->Application`** pane, deselect **`Enable application framework`** and select `Sub Main()` from the **`Startup form`** dropdown.

If `Sub Main()` doesn't exist yet, it can be added to a Module file. Here, the Module is named `Program.vb`.

```
Module Program
    Public Sub Main(args As String())
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(True)

    Dim startForm as Form = If(args.Any(
        Function(arg) arg.Equals("OSKNUM")), CType(New NumericForm(), Form), New AlphabetForm())
    Application.Run(startForm)
    End Sub
End Module
```

► If the OSK can be moved to UserControls, similar to what **`jmcilhinney`** suggested, run the default container Form and select the UserControl to show using the same logic (inspecting the command-line arguments):

```
Public Class AlphabetForm
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim args = My.Application.CommandLineArgs
        Dim uc = If(args.Any(
            Function(arg) arg.Equals("OSKNUM")), CType(New NumericUC(), UserControl), New AlphabetUC())
        Me.Controls.Add(uc)
        uc.BringToFront()
        uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    End Sub
End Class
```